# ¿Porque no puedo descargar un archivo en PHP?

Tags: php, html, archivo

Tengo un problema al querer descargar un archivo, en este caso de Excel. el código lo encontré en Internet, al pegarlo me sale error en el ***header***.

Le he buscado otros códigos, mas al parecer siguen teniendo problema en el header.
Funciona que al dar click a un botón me debe de descargar una plantilla de Excel para que se pueda llenar y después cargarla. Al Cargar el archivo no tengo problemas. Mi archivo de Excel Tiene celdas bloqueadas, no se si eso influya.

Este el código del post del botón

```html
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'descargar' ] ) ) {
   $file= 'plantilla_proyectosLuces.xlsx';
   if(is_file($file))
   {
    $filename="Plantilla_Productos.xlsx";//nombre que se la dara al descargar
    
    //header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename='descarga.xlsx'");
    //header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    //header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"\n");

    readfile($file);
   }
   else
  {
    die("Error: no se encontro el archivo a descargar");
   }
 }
```

y esta es la pantalla donde me salen los errores
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
aunque no se porque me salen esos caracteres

Comment: Eso pasa cuando imprimer algun valor antes de especificar algun header. Puedes confirmar eso?

Comment: gracias por el apoyo. pero no veo que tenga imprimiendo nada. no en el post ['descargar'], en los otros botones si imprimo, pero esos estan despues del de ***descargar***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira este código puede ayudar

```
$file = "location of file to download"
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

Presta atención al MIME `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');`

Aca un listado de los mas comunes http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Cuando usas `header("Content-Type: application/force-download");` imagina que el servidor va a responder así:

*Voy a enviar un archivo misterioso para que el cliente lo guarde en su disco duro como pueda, Pero y si no lo guarda?*

Saludos :)

Comment: De hecho ambas  respuestas me ayudaron. Si imprimia  algo antes del heladera cómo dijo Einer. Y también me ayudó el código de Rubén... Gracias a los dos por el apoyo